# php array data not working in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

The problem is in jQuery, `jsondata.uname` is not displaying any result. If I echo `$myarray` in PHP and use `data` in jQuery it will display the result in array form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button#myloginbtn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $('input#myusername').val();
        var password = $('input#mypassword').val();
        $.post('home.php', {
            domylogin: 'domylogin',
            username: username, 
            password: password 
        }, function(data) {
            jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
            $('p#auser').text(jsondata.uname); // This is not working
        });
    });
});
```

home.php:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['domylogin'])){
        $myuname = $_POST['username'];
        $mypword = $_POST['password'];
        // temporary testing, later i will return some data from database related to these values
        $myarray = array(); 
        $myarray['uname'] = $myuname;
        $myarray['pword'] = $mypword;

        echo json_encode($myarray);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `console.log(jsondata);`. Hope you will get what is wrong.

Comment: console.log(data); and check in browser

Comment: jQuery will automatically parse the response to an object for you. Using `JSON.parse()` on that object again will cause an error. Remove the `JSON.parse(data)` line and use `$('p#auser').text(data.uname)`

Comment: try this `{'domylogin':1, . . . }`.

Comment: @VairaMuthu where to put console.log(data);

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No sir its not working!

Comment: In that case check the console for errors to ensure the request is working and what the returned data is

Comment: try with console.dir(data);

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if i change like, `$('p#auser').text(data)` then it gives output: `{"uname":"admindda","pword":"da"}`

Comment: @ImranAslam below the function(data) { code and also add dataType: 'json'

Comment: Have you tried specifying the datatype of the `$.post()` method to json? e.g. `$.post(/*file*/, {/*data*/}, function(data){...}, "json")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for support, I had got the problem. I had some html code in my php file, on removing html code in 'home.php' everything works as supposed!

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file:-

```
 $myarray = array(); 
    if (isset($_POST['domylogin'])){
            $myuname = $_POST['username'];
            $mypword = $_POST['password'];             

            $myarray['uname'] = $myuname;
            $myarray['pword'] = $mypword;    

        }

 echo json_encode($myarray);
```

Write your AJAX call as below:-

```
$.post('home.php', {
    domylogin: 'domylogin',
    username: username, 
    password: password 
}) 
.done(function( data ) {  // Use done function        
    jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(jsondata) == false) // check jsondata is empty or not
    console.log(data);
    $('p#auser').text(jsondata.uname); 
 });
```

Hope it will help you:-

Comment: Check my updated answer. Do you get data in done function?

Comment: did everything, still no luck!